# How can I setup a nginx reverse proxy to display sites on different servers on my network to different specific domains

Tags: linux, nginx, ubuntu

So far I have this for my reverse proxy settings:

```
 server {
        server_name subdomain1.DOMAIN.net;
        location / {
            proxy_pass       http://192.168.1.156:9090;
        }
 }
 server {
        server_name subdomain2.DOMAIN.net;
        location / {
            proxy_pass       http://192.168.1.156:9091;
        }
 }
```

How ever it's just reporting back a 502 bad gateway when I check them. For more clarification nginx is running on a VM ubuntu server while the sites i'd like to access are running on another server on the same network. I'd like to know what i'm doing wrong here would really like to get it working.

Comment: Since every requests to the upstream servers are in HTTP, you can easily use a tool like Wireshark to analyze the requests/responses and learn what's wrong. Such 502 usually indicates that the upstream dislikes the requests. The packets can tell you more.

Comment: did you [read the manual?](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) most request require the domain name of it so far ```proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;``` should be always used in most cases